# Grouping numbers in a list

Tags: algorithm

I came across the following question,

You are given an array A of n elements. These elements are now added to a new list L which is initially empty , in a certain order based on the given q queries.

- In each query you are given an integer i that corresponds to A[i] in the array A. This means that you have to add the element A[i] to the list L.
- After each element is added to the list L, make groups among the elements in the list L. Two elements will be in same group if their indexes in the array A are consecutive.
- For each group we define the group’s value as **axb** where a is the largest value in that group and b is the size of that group.

Print the maximum group value among all the groups that are formed after each element is added to the list L.

My approach was to use a `map<int,vector<int>>` where key is the group number and value is a vector containing group size, max. of group. I also had an array g  and g[i] indicated group number of a[i], -1 if it is not in any group. The code below is a part of my implementation, but I'm sure there are better ways to solve this question as this solution of mine gave TLE and WA in some cases,and I can't seem to figure out the correct approach. Pls suggest optimal way to solve this.

```
int g[a.size()+2];       //+2 because queries start with index 1, and g[i] corresponds to a[i-1] 
for(int i=0;i<a.size()+2;i++)
    g[i]=-1;
int gno=1;
map<int,vector<int> > m;
vector<int> ans;
int mx=0;
for(unsigned int i=0;i<queries.size();i++){
    int q = queries[i];
    if(g[q-1]==-1 && g[q+1]==-1){
      //create new group with current eleent as first element
        g[q] = gno;        //gno is the group number.
        vector<int> v;

        v.push_back(1);
        v.push_back(a[q-1]);
        m[gno]=v;
        mx = max(mx,m[gno][0]*m[gno][1]);
        gno++;
    }
    else if(g[q-1]!=-1 && g[q+1]==-1){
      //join current element to left group
        g[q] = g[q-1];
        m[g[q]][0]++;
        m[g[q]][1] = max(m[g[q]][1],a[q-1]);
        mx = max(mx,m[g[q]][0]*m[g[q]][1]);
    }
    else if(g[q-1]==-1 && g[q+1]!=-1){
      //join current element to right group
        g[q] = g[q+1];
        m[g[q]][0]++;
        m[g[q]][1] = max(m[g[q]][1],a[q-1]);
        mx = max(mx,m[g[q]][0]*m[g[q]][1]);
    }
    else{
       //join both groups to left and right
        g[q]=g[q-1];
        int g1 = g[q];
        int i;
        m[g[q]][0] += 1 + m[g[q+1]][0];
        m[g[q]][1] = max(m[g[q]][1],max(a[q-1],m[g[q+1]][1]));
        for(i=q+1;g[i]==g[i+1];i++){
            g[i]=g1;
        }
        g[i]=g1;
        mx = max(mx,m[g[q]][0]*m[g[q]][1]);
    }
    ans.push_back(mx);
}
```

.

Comment: Can the same index be queried twice? What are the ranges for *n* and *q*?

Comment: Yes they can be although i believe it won't make any difference. Ranges are from 1 to 10^9 for n and 1 to 10^6 for q

Answer (score 0):

I would not actually build list L. It may be too costly in time to find what to do with a new value: is it a new group on itself, does it extend an existing group, do two groups need to merge into one? If the first values are all far apart, you'll have many groups, and you need to iterate them with each new incoming value: this is not efficient.

I would just collect all the values first and only then see how they fit in groups.

There are two ways to collect the values:

1. Store them in a list, and when all values have been collected, sort the list in ascending order
2. Flag the entry in an array of booleans of size *n*. This way you do not have to sort it, but afterwards you do need to iterate the whole array to find the values in ascending order.

Method 1 will be the best when *q* is a lot less than *n*. Method 2 will be better for greater *q*.

With both methods you'll be able to iterate over the found values in ascending order, and while doing so you can identify the groups, their value, and also keep track of the largest group-value. Only one sweep is needed to find the answer.

Comment: Since we need to output the maximum group value after each query, approach 1 of storing them in a list then finding the max later will not work. Thats why I went with the map solution.

Answer (score 0):

Let's start with two simplifying assumptions:

- no duplicates. Once a given index `i` has been "queried", it will never be queried again.
- no negative numbers. All elements are positive or zero, so the largest value in a group is always positive or zero, so expanding a group (or merging two groups) will never cause the overall "maximum group value" to decrease.

(Further below I'll show how to *not* require those assumptions, but for now this will simplify the picture.)

So, whenever we "query" an index `i`, there are four cases:

- `i-1` is currently the right-endpoint of a group (by which I mean its greatest index) and `i+1` is currently the left-endpoint of another group.

  - In this case, we need to merge the two groups into a single group, with `i` bridging the gap between them.
- `i-1` is currently the right-endpoint of a group, but `i+1` is not currently in any group.

  - In this case we need to extend the group to cover `i`.
- `i-1` is not currently in any group, but `i+1` is currently the left-endpoint of a group.

  - In this case, as in the previous case, we need to extend the group to cover `i`.
- Neither `i-1` nor `i+1` is in a group.

  - In this case, we have a new group with just one element.

In all cases, the key thing to note is that we're only interested in the *endpoints* of groups. So we don't need a general mapping from indices to their groups . . . which is good, because when we merge two groups, it would be expensive to then go and update every single index from one group to point to the other.

So we just need three mappings:

```
std::unordered_map<int, int> map_from_left_endpoint_to_right_endpoint;
std::unordered_map<int, int> map_from_right_endpoint_to_left_endpoint;
std::unordered_map<int, int> map_from_left_endpoint_to_largest_value;
```

To distinguish the four cases, we use e.g. `map_from_right_endpoint_to_left_endpoint.find(i - 1)` (which returns an iterator pointing to the left-endpoint of the group that `i-1` is the right-endpoint of, if applicable; otherwise it returns `map_from_right_endpoint_to_left_endpoint.end()`). We then delete entries as they become no-longer-applicable (due to groups being extended or merged in a given direction), in addition to (obviously) inserting new entries, and updating the values of existing entries.

In addition to those values, we also need an

```
int maximum_group_value = 0;
```

and whenever we extend a group or merge two groups, we check whether the value of the resulting group (meaning its `largest_value * (right_endpoint - left_endpoint + 1`) is greater than `maximum_group_value`. If so, we update `maximum_group_value` and return it; if not, we return `maximum_group_value` as-is.

---

Now, what if duplicates *are* allowed, such that a given index `i` might be "queried" after it already belongs to a group?

The simplest approach is to simply keep track of which `i`-s have already been queried; but a more elegant approach, if desired, might be to change `map_from_left_endpoint_to_right_endpoint` from a `std::unordered_map` to a `std::map`, and then use something like this:

```
bool is_already_in_a_group(
    std::map<int, int> const & map_from_left_endpoint_to_right_endpoint,
    int const i) {
  // get iterator to first element *after* index (or to 'end()' if no such):
  auto iter = map_from_left_endpoint_to_right_endpoint.upper_bound(index);
  // if that pointer points to 'begin()', then there are no elements
  // at or before index:
  if (iter == map_from_left_endpoint_to_right_endpoint.begin()) {
    return false;
  }
  // otherwise, move iterator to point to the last element whose key is
  // less than or equal to index:
  --iter;
  // . . . and check whether the value of that element is greater than
  // or equal to index (meaning that [key, value] spans index):
  return iter->second >= index;
}
```

to check if the greatest key in `map_from_left_endpoint_to_right_endpoint` that is less than or equal to `i` is mapped to a value that is greater than or equal to `i`.

This adds a fifth case to our case analysis above — "if `i` is already inside a group, just do nothing and return `maximum_group_value`" — but other than that, has no effect.

Note that this same approach also lets us eliminate `map_from_right_endpoint_to_left_endpoint`, if we want: the above function could easily be tweaked to `int get_left_endpoint_for_right_endpoint` by changing its `return` statement to `return iter->second == index ? iter->first : -1;`.

At this point it becomes sensible to define a `Group` class with three fields (`left_endpoint`, `right_endpoint`, and `largest_value`), and just keep a single `map_from_left_endpoint_to_group`.

---

Lastly — what if negative values are allowed, such that the "maximum group value" can actually *decrease* as the result of a query? (For example, if the array elements are `[-1, -10]` and the queries are `i=0`, `i=1`, then the results are `maximum_group_value=-1`, `maximum_group_value=-2`.) In such a case, we need to keep track of the values of all current groups, because any one of them might suddenly become the maximum.

For that, instead of storing a single `int maximum_group_value`, we can maintain a heap of groups, ordered by value, that we push into every time we create/extend/merge groups. (We can just use a `std::vector<Group>` for this, plus `std::push_heap` with an appropriate comparator, or with an appropriate definition for `operator<(Group const &, Group const &)`.) After each query, we check if the top group on the heap (the first element in the vector) is still a group that actually exists; if so, we return its value, otherwise we pop it (using `std::pop_heap`) and repeat.

As an optimization, we can *also* store `int maximum_group_value`, and eliminate the heap once we've encountered a nonnegative array-element (since as soon as a given group contains a nonnegative array-element, its value can never decrease again, and obviously the maximum group value will be the value of one of those groups).